# Is it possible for Barcode Auto generate for products?

Tags: magento-1.9, barcode

I want to auto generate a barcode for products and have to download that barcode. Is it possible in magento for free? Share me if any extension or codes available

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you, it seems to do what you are looking for: https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-ean-generator